# Sharing mongoose model across multiple apps on different server

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a collection 'collectionA' with model and schema created in app 'A' on a server 1. All of the data for this collection is created using app 'A'.

I want to use the same database and collection through different app 'B' running on a different physical server 2.

Reading through SO, seems best way is to define schema and model in external library and use in both app A and app B. Since my App A and B are on two different server, how do I create a shared lib in this case.

or is there a better solution to achieve this behavior ?

Thanks

Comment: Create a private npm package with models and use it in both projects.

Comment: and use something like git to host the package ?

Comment: yes, if you haven't own private registry, then you can store it on github or bitbucket

Comment: okay, in case app B, just need to view the collection in the database  (no CRUD operations from app B), do I still need to require the shared library ?

Comment: if app B uses mongoose models, it needs that library, of course.